# Mysql query join table and let fill with empty if value same

Tags: mysql

I Have problem with joining 2 table
this is mysql query

> select *
>   from tbl_perspective a
>   inner join tbl_objective b on b.idperspective=a.idperspective

The result is:
[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9e5dK.png)

I Want to display first row of perspectivename and blank or null

Final Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC57m.png)

Comment: I figured out what you are asking, but please edit your question and include your sample input and output as _text_, formatted in your question with four leading spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Anwr Rawk simply you can use LEFT JOIN

```
 select * from tbl_perspective as a 
     left join 
 tbl_objective as b 
 on b.idperspective=a.idperspective
```

Answer (score 0):

Join to a subquery which identifies the first row for each `idperspective` group:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl_perspective t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT idperspective, MIN(idobjective) AS min_idobjective
    FROM tbl_perspective
    GROUP BY idperspective
) t2
    ON t1.idperspective = t2.idperspective AND
       t1.idobjective   = t2.min_idobjective;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use LEFT JOIN to include all results, like this : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins